# Improve a script to generally check status of several git repos

Tags: bash, shell

I've tried to write a bash script that gives me a general overview of the status of git repos I have cloned/created. It's not meant to replace `git status` by any means, but give an overview of several repos.

Keep in mind I'm not the most knowledgeable about bash scripting AND git, so I imagine there is a better way to do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Help from: http://www.leancrew.com/all-this/2010/12/batch-comparison-of-git-repositories/

index=0
gitrepos=()

#TODO: There has got to be a better way to add all these folders to the array
#add repos folder
for d in ~/repos/*; do
    gitrepos[(index+=1)]="$d"
done

#add other important folders
gitrepos[(index+=1)]=~/.vim
gitrepos[(index+=1)]=~/dot_files
gitrepos[(index+=1)]=~/bin

for d in "${gitrepos[@]}"; do
    if [ -e $d ]; then
        cd $d
    else
        echo " Did not find repo: $d"
        continue
    fi

    reponame="`basename $d`"

    ok=true
    git fetch --quiet origin 2>/dev/null
    if [ ! -z "`git diff HEAD origin/HEAD 2> /dev/null`" ]; then
        echo " $reponame --> Out of sync with origin/HEAD"
        ok=false
    fi
    if [ ! -z "`git ls-files --other --exclude-standard 2> /dev/null`" ]; then
        echo " $reponame --> Untracked files present"
        ok=false
    fi
    if [ ! -z "`git diff --cached --shortstat 2> /dev/null`" ]; then
        echo " $reponame --> Changes to be committed"
        ok=false
    fi
    if [ ! -z "`git diff --shortstat 2> /dev/null`" ]; then
        echo " $reponame --> Changes to be staged/committed"
        ok=false
    fi
    if $ok; then
        echo " OK --> $reponame"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Have you tried [`fgit`](https://github.com/l0b0/fgit)? It's served me well for years. Disclaimer: I'm the author.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is a better way of filling an array. You can use globbing inside of array parens. Also I suggest being explicit about what you do in bash and use `declare -a` to declare arrays and later on `declare` for other variables

```
declare -a repos=(~/repos/* ~/.vim ~/dot_files ~/bin)
```

In case of adding stuff to an array, after it got created:

```
repos+=("more stuff" here)
```

Maybe you want to name you iterating variable more verbose, instead of `d` `repodir` or something.

Your first if contains a `continue` so you can emphasize on this one and just go on with no `else`. Also don't miss the double quotes in case of directory names with spaces in them. Also you should check for `-d` since you `cd` into it.

```
if [ -d "$d" ]; then
  echo "No repo at $d"
  continue
fi
cd "$d"
```

`` [ ! -z "`cmd`" ] `` is more verbose than it needs to be. You can just do `` [ "`cmd`" ] ``.

Read the "Arrays" chapter in the bash manpage.

I attach my test file for this answer which also shows functions and some refactoring which allows to discard this `ok` variable.

```
#!/bin/bash
main() {
    local -a repos=(* /foo/bar)
    echo -e "repos: ${repos[@]}"
    for path in "${repos[@]}"; do
      check_repo "$path"
    done
}

check_repo() {
    local path="$1"
    local name="`basename "$path"`"
    local report=""
    if [ ! -d "$path" ]; then
      echo -e "$name\n not a directory: $path"
      return
    fi
    cd "$path"
    if [ "`echo foo 2> /dev/null`" ]; then
        report+="\n oh oh"
    fi
    cd - > /dev/null
    if [ -z "$report" ]; then
        report+="\n OK"
    fi
    echo -e "$name$report"
}

main
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments! They have taught me quite a lot about bash.

Comment: Me too. Never have read "Arrays" before.